# js not submitting form by setting dynamic action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

working on wordpress, having page template, there is ajax call which check the voucher code and set the action dynamically, and submit form to redeem voucher,

```
$.ajax({ 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: ajaxurl, 
                    data: action_data, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) { 
                        $(".loading").hide();
                        btn.prop('disabled',false);
                        btn.removeAttr("disabled");

                        if(response.status==1){
                            $(".response").html(response.message);
                            $(".response").show().delay(2000).hide(0);
                            var redirectUrl = "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/"+response.redirect_link+"/";
                            alert(redirectUrl);

                            form.attr('action',redirectUrl);


                        }else{
                            $("#voucher_code").addClass("error-fld");
                            $(".response").html(response.message);
                            $(".response").show().delay(3000).hide(0);
                            //return true;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Also i have rule in my htaccess that all urls should append "/" in the end   otherwise redirect it to referrer URL,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1404/feedback
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1740/feedback
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Problem if i hardcode action in  tag it works fine, but through setting jquery doesn't submit. also i have check the response in ajax also alerted redirect link have "/" also in the end, and in network tab, however it redirect to dynamic url through jquery, but show 302 error in network tab, sorry for my bad english , open to answer any question, any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but it appears you are simply changing the "action" attribute on the form, but you are not resubmitting the form. Try something like:

```
...    
form.attr('action',redirectUrl);
form.submit();
...
```